# Unable to cast type of parameter from Array.find() with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following `OrganisationInterface` type:

```
export declare interface OrganisationInterface {
    documents?: {
        [documentType: OrganisationDocumentTypesList]: { // enum
            id: string;
            name: string;
            src?: string;
        }
    };
}
```

In my executable code I have the following:

```
const organisation = { ...<OrganisationInterface>organisationSnap.data(), id: organisationId }

// Attempt 1 - Have typescript infer the type of 'record' variable
// TS throws error: 'record' is of type 'unknown'
const documentRecord = Object.values(organisation?.documents ?? {}).find((record) => record.id! === fileId)

// Attempt 2 - Cast 'record'
// TS throws error: No overload matches this call
const documentRecord = Object.values(organisation?.documents ?? {}).find((<OrganisationInterface['documents']>record) => record.id! === fileId)

// Attempt 3 - Cast 'record' variable on right side of 'find' method
// TS throws error - 'documents' is possibly undefined
const documentRecord = Object.values(organisation?.documents ?? {}).find((record) => (<OrganisationInterface['documents']>record).id! === fileId)

// Attempt 4 - Change 'documents' subobject from optional to required
// TS throws error - Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'
const documentRecord = Object.values(organisation?.documents ?? {}).find((record) => (<Required<OrganisationInterface>['documents']>record).id! === fileId)
```

Why does TS refuse to let me assign the type of the `record` variable returned via the `Array.find()` function?

Comment: Did you try to cast the array? `Object.values(organisation?.documents ?? {}) as OrganisationInterface>['documents'][]`?

Comment: When I try that, TS gives me a `'record' is of type 'unknown'` error

Comment: How is `OrganisationDocumentTypesList` defined?

Comment: `(Object.values(organisation?.documents ?? {}) as OrganisationInterface>['documents'][]).find((record: OrganisationInterface>['documents']) => record.id! === fileId)` what about this?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE; the only errors present should be the ones you're asking about (e.g., fix anything from [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5O8VW) that isn't related to your question)

Answer (score -1):

When you look at the definition of `Object.values` : `values<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): T[];` you can see that the type is inferred.

You can alias your indexed type :

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
type Document = Values<NonNullable<OrganisationInterface['documents']>>
```

then you can pass that return type :

```
const documentRecord = Object.values<MyDocument>(organisation?.documents ?? {}).find((record) => record?.id === fileId)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-EDxkBk9gyjmUjxYABKGb9Pxg6IAVmosAA6IPw9BvBY1z4ACi5eKFIC8HerSywia8XjYEgAlB35SBlIPBz7M4vVt8t36J6VVis1vLFcpF9IgA)

Comment: The indexed type `MyDocument` can be derived like this: `type Values<T> = T[keyof T]; type Document = Values<NonNullable<OrganisationInterface['documents']>>` [modified playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0b9Ow)